# Distract part of a number

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

How can I obtain via sql/Impala the OPP number from Opportunities, without the subjects in a list with more that 3000 different subjects? So I want a variable Opportunity_two with the OPP number like OPP00337839 only. 
What do you look up? How do you do something like this??

```
Opportunities
OPP00337839 Biology
OPP00446759 Geography
OPP06293521 Sports
OPP96745240 Math
```

Comment: Is that number always at the start of the text and does it always have the same size? Then use some "substring"-like operation. In general: how would *you* identify that number, then teach the system to use that same method

Comment: yes, it consistently starts with opp and 8 digits (0-9)

Comment: Does simple `select substr(opportunities, 1, instr(opportunities, ' ')-1) from tablename` work?

Answer (score 0):

Find the space using Charindex and select everything up to that number (minus 1 to remove trailing space!)

```
DECLARE @String varchar(50) = 'OPP00337839 Biology'
SELECT LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(' ' ,@String)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers look like they are fixed lengths, so you can just do:

```
select left(opportunities, 11) as opportunity_number
```

If the length can vary, I would recommend:

```
select left(opportunities, charindex(' ', opportunities + ' ') - 1) as opportunity_number
```

This will handle the situation where the value does not have a space.